# How to simulate a click event when document onready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The two method below are not working for me; I need the button `click` event to fire with the `document onready` event. (`#usrpost` is a button element.)

```
$(function() {
   $("#usrpost").trigger("click");
   $("#usrpost").live("click",function() {
       //do something.
    });
});
```

I've also tried the following:

```
$(function() {
   $("#usrpost")[0].click();
   $("#usrpost").live("click",function() {
       //do something.
    });
});
```

Comment: `function` not `fucntion`. Also, what version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: Also, use `//` or `/* */` notation for comments

Comment: You are referring to usrpost by ID (#usrpost) but also referencing the first instance of it. IDs should only be used if there is only one instance of the element on the page, so you should be using a class. (.usrpost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the event after the handler is added(apart from the spelling issue, also assuming you are using jQuery < 1.9)

```
$(function () {

    $("#usrpost").live("click", function () {

        //do something.
    });
    //fire it after the handler is added
    $("#usrpost").click();

});
```

Note: If you are using jQuery >= 1.7 use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $("#usrpost").on("click", function() {
        //do something.
    });
    $("#usrpost").click();
});
```

You had a typo in "function"

Answer (score 0):

You must call the .click() after bind the event:

```
$(function() {
   $("#usrpost").live("click",function() {
       //do something.
   });
   $("#usrpost")[0].click();
});
```

.live() is also now deprecated in favour of .on():

```
$(function() {
   $('body').on('click', "#usrpost", function() {
       //do something.
   });
   $("#usrpost")[0].click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the event too

```
$("#usrpost").trigger("click");
```